# Is AWS Glue + Athena/Hive right choice to replace complex SQL queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, aws-glue

I have been using AWS Athena to query analytics data stored on S3 across several tables. Over a period of time I have come up with 2-3 complex SQL queries (involving several joins) for pulling relevant data. Since, Athena is for ad-hoc queries (and not predefined queries), besides prohibitive costs for processing several TB and 30 minute timeout, I am looking for alternatives.

Two alternatives that I can think of are:

1. Use Presto based EMR cluster and run existing query. It removes the 30 minute limit and (might) reduce costs ($5/TB). However, the cons are reprocessing the same data on successive runs.
2. Do ETL (such as through AWS Glue) and denormalise data. This should reduce repeated joins, as only incremental data is processed. Subsequently query the flattened data with some SQL interface - Athena/Hive. However, I am not sure if denormalisation is a good idea, besides the cost of storing redundant (huge) data.

Which of these is a better choice or is there a better standard technique for this issue?

Comment: There is no silver bullet. If you denormalise, you create a copy that you need to keep in sync. And make sure your ETL didn't fail (otherwise your queries will work but get wrong results). If you're OK managing this (paying with your time) then you can compare query costs vs increased storage costs. Also, sometimes, denormalisation is the only way to meet response time expectations. I would personally avoid denormalisation unless a must, so i suggest give option 1 and especially @KamilBajdaPawlikowski's proposal a try.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to do 2 (denormalization) and then 1 (run Presto over the optimized data layout).
Also, Presto with Cost-Based Optimizer might be worth a look: https://www.starburstdata.com/technical-blog/starburst-presto-on-aws-18x-faster-than-emr/

Answer (score 0):

Denormalization of the Data depends on your use case but mostly preferred for s3/hdfs structures. you can follow this link for better Athena storing and performance:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/

Comment: I've alread incorporated most of those optimisations. But as I guess is the case, Athena is for ad-hoc queries and I plan to continue using Athena for them. However, my question was for predefined queries - long running queries that (currently) do lots of joins, are relatively stable and are supposed to run periodically to pull analytics data.

Can you help point me to any reference that states that denormalisation is preferred fro s3/hdfs structure?